# How to deal with large React applications

Tags: reactjs

Is there some pattern for development of large React applications?

For example, in the mobile world we have MVVM, VIPER, MVP, MVC, etc.

I want to know, besides Atomic design, if is there another way to handle with a lot of components.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [Brad Frost's Atomic Component pattern](https://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/). I have used it in a couple of production applications. It is a guideline that helps you build re-useable components. One example of atomic component design would be your navigation. Since the mobile navigation is just a Drawer component and it contains the same content as your desktop navigation you would build the following components with the following directory  structure:

```
/components
|-/atoms
|  |-/NavigationItem
|  |-/NavigationList
|-/molecules
   |-/NavigationDrawer
   |-/Header
```

So NavigationList would be a component that you pass your links to. You could pass a data structure that resembles:

```
interface NavigationLink {
  label: string
  destination: string
}
```

The Header component and the Drawer component would use the NavigationList component to build our your NavigationLinks while being very maintainable.